Docker container exits immediately with "pywintypes.error: (109, 'ReadFile', 'pipe has ended')" when building a project in Windows
Project:https://github.com/Suresoft-GLaDOS/bugscpp
I am following the instructions provided in the README file to build and run a project using Docker on Windows 10. I successfully set up the environment and followed all the steps, but when I reach the build step, I encounter the following error:109err
Steps I followed:

Cloned the repository: Cloned the project from GitHub and navigated to the project directory.
Set up the environment: Followed the instructions to set up Python virtual environment and installed all dependencies.
Attempted to build the project: Ran the command python bugscpp/bugscpp.py build ./cpp_peglib/buggy-1 as instructed in the README.

What I have tried:

Checked Docker container status: The container starts but exits almost immediately.
Viewed container logs: There are no specific error messages in the logs that indicate what went wrong.
Pulled the latest Docker image: Used docker pull hschoe/defects4cpp-ubuntu:cpp_peglib, but the issue persists.
Ensured Docker is running: Docker Desktop is running, and other Docker commands work as expected.

Question:
Why am I encountering the "pywintypes.error: (109, 'ReadFile', 'pipe has ended.')" error when trying to build this project with Docker on Windows, and how can I resolve it?
Any advice or insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
